# elfinder 2.1.64 error : https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror on the remote server but not on localhost

Tags: image, ckeditor, elfinder, symfony5.4

I installed helios elfinder2.1.64 for symfony 5.4 on my local, it works fine, but on the remote server I get an error :Script error for "elfinder"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
I followed all the installation recommandations I found on https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle.
Could somebody help me .
Thanks

Alain

Under easyadmin, in a CKeditorfield, I tried to include an image in a text. The button "browse the server" is in the select image window but when I click on this button, I got this error.